# Function returning type used in a function taking a generic type parameter

Tags: generics, f#, first-class

So I have this code:

```
type Zero = One = 1 | Two = 2 | Three = 3
type Four = Five = 5 | Six = 6 | Seven = 7

let test_1 (x : bool) : Type =
    if x
    then typeof<Zero>
    else typeof<Four>

let test_2 () =
     let ty = test_1 true
     let e = enum<ty>(1)
     ...
```

However on the last line, I get an error: `Type ty not defined.`

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Or maybe something like this:

```
let test_3 (x : bool) (i : int) : obj =
    if x
    then enum<Zero>(i) :> obj
    else enum<Four>(i) :> obj
```

I was thinking would there be some way to regain type safety?

Maybe something like this?

```
let test_4 (x : bool) (i : int) : obj * Type =
    if x
    then enum<Zero>(i) :> obj, typeof<Zero>
    else enum<Four>(i) :> obj, typeof<Four>
```

Then use it as so:

```
let test_5 () =
    let v,t = test_4 true 1
    let o = v :?> t
    ...
```

This complains on the last line with t not defined.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to be able to return these different enums without resorting to wrapping Zero and Four into a DU.

Comment: Type parameters must be statically known, they can't be the result of a dynamic computation.

Comment: A `Type` instance exists at runtime; `enum` expects a compile-time argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, "type safety" implies you (the compiler) know the type **statically** (without executing code). By casting to `obj` you loose that knowledge. Adding a *runtime* type (`typeof`) does not help. Even if you could use the second value of the returned tuple, how would that help? Your program code would be hard-coded for whatever `true|false` value you had.

If this value is not known at compile time (e.g. read from console), what type would you assume? What should `t` be in the following binding?

```
let o : t = test someBool someInt
```

It could be either `Zero` or `Four`, that is `Zero | Four`, that is `type Either = Zero | Four`, that is

```
type EitherEnum =
| Z of Zero
| F of Four
```

... a discriminated union, as you figured out already.

> Basically what I'm trying to do is to be able to return these different enums without resorting to wrapping Zero and Four into a DU.

You figured out how to do that already: cast to `obj` and loose type safety. You can't have it both ways.

What you are looking for are [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), something e.g. [F*](https://www.fstar-lang.org/) provides.